# Select Student based on their Course Score SQL

Tags: sql, merge

I have three tables.

`Student (s_id, s_name)`

`Course (c_id, c_name)`

`Score (s_id, c_id, s_s_score)`

Every student can pick multiple courses, every courses has a score. How to find student id and name whose average score greater than 60?

My thoughts:

```
SELECT s_id, s_name FROM Student LEFT JOIN Score ON s_id LEFT JOIN
Course ON c_id  
WHERE AVG(s_s_score) > 60
```

I think something along this line but I have trouble with three table joins

My thoughts:

```
SELECT s_id, s_name FROM Student LEFT JOIN Score ON s_id LEFT JOIN 
Course ON c_id  
WHERE AVG(s_s_score) > 60
```

I think something along this line but I have trouble with three table joins

Comment: You need columns only from student table, then why are you trying to join course table? Your required data is in student and scorer table only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT std.s_id, std.s_name 
FROM Student std
LEFT JOIN Score s ON s.s_id = std.s_id 
LEFT JOIN Course c ON c.c_id = s.c_id
WHERE AVG(s.s_s_score) > 60;
```

---

You don't need course table for this, so here it is without course tbl.

---

```
SELECT std.s_id, std.s_name FROM Student std
LEFT JOIN Score s ON s.s_id = std.s_id
WHERE AVG(s.s_s_score) > 60;
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on db, there are few things.

1. You need to specify the joins, so the tables know what to join
   where.
2. You should specify how to group the results (by students in this
   case)
3. You should change WHERE to HAVING, as WHERE is used for checking
   columns and having allows usage of functions (AVG)

   ```
   SELECT Student.s_id, Student.s_name 
   FROM Student
   LEFT JOIN Score ON Student.s_id = Score.s_id 
   LEFT JOIN Course ON Course.c_id = Score.c_id 
   GROUP BY Student.s_id
   HAVING AVG(s_s_score) > 60;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You only need one table since score table has student_id and scores.

For selecting would be something like:

```
select student_id 
from
score
having
avg(grade) > 60
```